Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.Communication.Administration.EmailClient]
EDIT: I have now added the code
I'm writing a Powershell script that must be able to send an email using Azures communication service. I keep getting the error:
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.Communication.Administration.EmailClient].
At C:\Users\xxxxx\nmyscript.ps1:31 char:20+ ... ailClient = [Microsoft.Azure.Communication.Administration.EmailClient ...
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Azure...ion.EmailClient:TypeName) [], Run
   timeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

when trying to run the script eventhough I import the module Import-Module -Name Az.Communication in the script. Can anybody help?
I have tried to uninstall the module and reinstall the module.
This is the first iteration of the code, on the long run it has to become more generic.
Connect-AzAccount
Import-Module -Name Az.Communication

$SenderEmailAddress = xx.azurecomm.net"
$ReceiverEmailAddress = "xx@xx.com"
$EmailConnectionString = "endpoint=xxx"

function Send-Email {
    param (
        [string]$Subject,
        [string]$Body
    )

    $Message = @{
        "content" = @{
            "subject" = $Subject
            "plainText" = $Body
        }
        "recipients" = @{
            "to" = @(
                @{
                    "address" = $ReceiverEmailAddress
                }
            )
        }
        "senderAddress" = $SenderEmailAddress
    }

    $EmailClient = [Microsoft.Azure.Communication.Administration.EmailClient]::from_connection_string($EmailConnectionString)
    if ($EmailClient -ne $null) {
        $EmailClient.begin_send($Message)
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failed to create EmailClient. Check connection string and module installation."
    }
    $EmailClient.begin_send($Message)
}

$SevenDaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$UnusedResources = Get-AzResource | Where-Object { $_.Properties.LastModifiedTime -lt $SevenDaysAgo }

if ($UnusedResources.Count -gt 0) {
    $Subject = "Unused Azure Resources in Last 7 Days"
    $Body = "The following Azure resources have not been in use in the last 7 days:`n`n"
    foreach ($Resource in $UnusedResources) {
        $Body += "Resource Name: $($Resource.Name)`nResource Type: $($Resource.Type)`nLast Modified Time: $($Resource.Properties.LastModifiedTime)`n`n"
    }
    Send-Email -Subject $Subject -Body $Body
}
else {
    Write-Output "No unused resources found in the last 7 days."
}



Did you install Azure Powershell? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azure-powershell?view=azps-11.5.0

Hey, could you please try to add more information. Like code

Unsure how you get that this Az module will give you access to that class. That class is in an assembly not used by this module afaik. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.communication.email?view=azure-dotnet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you share the code tried so far? @user22439645

I have now added the code in the post :-)

@SantiagoSquarzon I'm pretty new to Azure in generalt and have evner used the email service before. I have just tried to figure out what to do based on the documentation I could find

@jdweng Yes the azure powershell has been installed. I can also connect to azure through the code.

Where are the credentials?  The FROM address and the credentials have to be from the same user account.  It you read error carefully it does NOT say the method is missing, it says ID (FullyQualifiedErrorId) is bad.

Error 80040154 is wrong version of ActiveX component.  Are you using any ActiveX in the excel macro?  You should get same error is you open workbook from file explorer or excel provided macros are enabled.  I suspect when you are opening the workbook (not from PS) the macro is not running.

I found this guide https://medium.com/@abhinavch53/azure-sandbox-resource-deletion-automation-using-python-235b310348bd
Changed to using python, no I have no issues.
